# Simple query returning "you tried to assign the Null value to a variable that is not a Variant data type" error

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here's the query:

```
UPDATE T_Incoming 
SET T_Incoming.upnx = [CUPN] + [C] / 10, 
    T_Incoming.cupnx = [CUPN] + [C] / 10, 
    T_Incoming.UPN = IIF([UPN] IS NULL, [CUPN], [UPN]), 
    T_Incoming.cupnxp = [CUPN] + [C] / 10 + 0.01, 
    T_Incoming.cupnxpi = [CUPN] + [C] / 10 + 0.011
WHERE (((T_Incoming.ADD) = True));
```

I've used this query for years without any issues, and this just popped up out of nowhere. Any ideas as to why that could be?

Here's a sample of the input it receives from a single row of data:

```
upnx: 123456789
cupnx: null
UPN: null
CUPN: 50527
cupnxp: null
cupnxpi: null
ADD: -1
```

And here are the data types from the SQL Server table:

```
upnx: float
cupnx: float
UPN: float
CUPN: float
cupnxp: float
cupnxpi: float
ADD: bit
```

Comment: Something changed. Are you sure that data was previously handled? What is [C]?

Comment: [C] is just a float we use to track the number of purchases a person has made. So CUPN is an ID that gets assigned at first purchase, and C is used to create a decimal added onto the CUPN. So one purchase creates a 0.1 added. Two purchases would be a 0.2 added. Turns out the problem fixed itself somehow. The error has now disappeared entirely! No idea what happened...

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an answer to this. But the problem seems to have resolved itself. I have no idea how, but the error is no longer appearing.

Comment: My guess would be that there was a record with CUPN = NULL in the table.